# Can I see my Halo 5 Arena Ratings from before a reset?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

I worked hard to get into Diamond 3 in Team Slayer.  I understand why you would reset occasionally (one just happened over christmas) but can I prove that I was Diamond 3 anywhere in the game or on their website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can find what you are looking for on [Halo Waypoint](https://www.halowaypoint.com)

Just click on Games > Service Record and you should see this page (please excuse my pitiful score and K/D ratio):

[image]